# Create multidimensional arrays on json string

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Hy,

I'm banging my head against a wall because I don't seem to get that right...

I'm using the jqBarGraph.1.1 JS libary do display some data.

The data that I should display is within an JSON Object that I receive.

But here comes the clue, I have to create a multidimensional array in order to pass the data to the libary, or method that creates my bar charts.

The requirement for the libary is as follows:

```
var graphResolutionByYear = new Array(
        [[4238,4459,550],'21.04.2014'],
        [[4156,4453,550],'22.04.2014'],
        [[4424,4459,550],'23.04.2014'],
        [[4238,4459,550],'24.04.2014'],
        [[4156,4453,550],'25.04.2014'],
        [[4238,4459,550],'26.04.2014'],
        [[4238,4459,550],'27.04.2014']
    );
```

So what I have now is I need to somehow create the array from above after that I've called my `$.getJSON()`.

What I've done so far with googling and research is this:

```
function createBarChart(daten){
    var arraySize = daten["data"].length;
    var barValues = new Array(arraySize);


    $.each(daten["data"],function(i,val){
        var values = new Array();
        barValues[i] = new Array(3);
        barValues[i].push(daten["data"].prodDatum);


    });


}
```

The 3 value array is created within the barValues, but the prodDatum values, which is a value of the json is still missing. It is kind the "key".

The `$.getJSON` function calls the function `createBarChart()` and passes the JSON String.

The JSON String itself is nothing else than an array wth several data entries.

If anyone can push me in the right direction it would be awesome !

Thanks !

**Update:**

I've changed the markup to the following

```
 function createHochOfenChart(daten){

    var arraySize = daten["data"].length;
    var barValues = new Array(arraySize);


    $.each(daten["data"],function(i,val){
        var valus = new Array();
        barValues[i]=new Array(3);
        barValues[i].push("test");


    });

    console.debug(barValues);

 }
```

Now the 3 valued array turns into a 4 value array, so the "test" string is added to my new Array(3) initialized array. Does anybody know how to "tell" that this is a "multidimensional" entry ?

**Update 2:**

I've now reached the point were the first so to say array is filled with the data I need:

```
 function createHochOfenChart(daten){

    var arraySize = daten["data"].length;
    var barValues = new Array(arraySize);


    $.each(daten["data"],function(i,val){
        var valus = new Array();
        barValues[i]=new Array(3);
        barValues[i][0] = val.reSoll;
        barValues[i][1] = val.reIst;
        barValues[i][2] = val.reVorrat;
    });

    console.debug(barValues);

 }
```

The values are now put into the array, but I cannot add the a string with a date as working as a "key"...

Comment: hm, could you please provide src code you receive from getJson and what output you need ?

Comment: The getJSON is working fine I receive they data without any problems. Thats not even the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function take the daten['data'] array and create a list entry with 3 possitions array in first position and prodDatum value in second

```
function createHochOfenChart(daten){
    var barValues = daten["data"].map(function (e){
        var valus = new Array();
        valus.push([e.reSoll, e.reIst, e.reVorrat])
        valus.push(e.prodDatum);
        return valus
    })
    return barValues
}
```

Is what you wanted?

Comment: Hy I'm not sure, I have to iterate over the daten["data"] json array and have to take some values out of the daten["data"] json array and create exactly the same array as I described on top. I've made some progress which I will paste into the question in a sec !

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN ! Thanks pal ! You saved me hours of work ;-)